# Редактирование нескольких view model в одной форме

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Добрый день. Пишу приложение на WPF с использованием MVVP и Prism.
Есть таблица данных, каждая строка представлена простой view model. Есть задача - добавить возможность редактировать нескольких строк за раз, т.е. мультиедит.
Проблема в следующем - если некоторое свойство выбранных строк одинаково для всех строк, то в форму нужно загрузить значения этого свойства. Т.е. если выбрано 10 строк и у всех этих строк (читай view model) свойство Size = 10, то при открытии формы редактора это поле должно быть установлено в 10.

Проблема в том - как определить такие свойства.
Единственная идея - создать коллекцию, содержащую имена всех свойств (13 шт.). С помощью foreach идти по этой коллекции. На каждом проходе извлекать из всех выбранных строк значение свойства (через рефлексию) и сравнивать. Но этот подход довольно затратный. М.б. есть проще способ?

Вторая идея - запоминать значения всех свойств из первой строки (VM) и потом сравнивать все остальные строки с этими параметрами. Примерно вот так:

```
var size = selectedItems.First().Size;
if (selectedItems.All(item => item.Size == size)
{  // do some work   }
```

Но этот вариант также кажется грубым. Основная проблема в том, что из-за таких проверок форма с редактором появится с задержкой (если выбрано большое количество строк), что не есть хорошо. Правда если не найду элегантного решения - придется делать в лоб и использовать асинхронность.

Comment: Рефлексия затратна? По сравнению с чем? (А как вы думаете, как работает Binding к VM?)

Comment: А тип VM  строк заранее известен?

Comment: @VladD *"А как вы думаете, как работает Binding к VM?"* -- http://i2.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/217/594/FIHci.jpg

Comment: @VladD Считаю что рефлексия затратна т.к. может быть 20-30 строк в выборке. Тогда придется 20-30 раз извлекать 13 параметров через рефлексию и сравнивать их. Таким образом форма с редактором будет открываться с задержкой. Но могу ошибаться. Все строки (т.е VM) одного типа. Еще пришла одна идея - добавлю в описание.

Comment: @ВиталийЕфимов: Окей, а этот один тип фиксирован? Если да, почему бы просто не скастить к нему?

Comment: У меня уже изначально коллекция выбранных view model. View model содержит 13 свойств значения которых нужно неким образом извлечь (по имени свойства), проанализировать и если у всех VM в коллекции некоторое свойство одинаково - установить контексту редактора в это свойство это значение.

Comment: @ВиталийЕфимов: Ну вы бы спрофилировали. В Release-режиме и без отладчика. Рефлексия должна быть вполне себе быстрой для ваших нужд.